# How to intercept control move when editing a Delphi form

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm developing a visual component (VCL), a specialized TPanel. I need to intercept when the user moves a control dropped on my special panel while editing the form. I need to intercept the move to adjust visual properties of other controls dropped on the same special panel.

My question is: how can in intercept/detect/react to the move of a control dropped on a TCustomPanel derived component, while the user is editing the form within the IDE?

Comment: You can override `AlignControls`

Comment: Thanks  @kobik that is the right solution. If you rewrite it as an answer, I'll grant you the correct answer.

Comment: I'm very curious if this approach works.

Comment: Yes, overriding AlignControls works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could override `AlignControls` method of the container `TPanel.` the `AControl` argument will tell you which child control was moved or inserted into the container and react accordingly. You could then adjust the position of other child controls if needed.